# Python - Max retries exceeded with url (only on production server)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to connect to one webpage. This is my code:

```
class AddNewSite():

    def __init__(self, url, user=None, email=None, category=None, 
    subcategory=None, date_end=None):
        self.url = url
        self.user = user
        self.email = email
        req = Request(self.url, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 
   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) \
                AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 \
                Safari/537.36'})
        self.page = urlopen(req).read()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page)
        self.meta = self.soup.find_all('meta')
```

In my views.py (It is a Django project) I have:

```
try:
    page = AddNewSite(siteurl, user)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
                                 'ERROR')
            return render(request, 'mainapp/subcategory.html', context)
```

Everything works fine on localhost. It connects to site without eny errors. On production server I get an exception. Below I paste error from logs.

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='exeo.pl', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: 
/ (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
object at 0x80897ff98>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] 
Operation timed out',))
HTTPConnectionPool(host='exeo.pl', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: 
/ (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
object at 0x80940aeb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] 
Operation timed out',))
HTTPConnectionPool(host='exeo.pl', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: 
/ (Caused by 
NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
object at 0x80949fdd8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] 
Operation timed out',))
<urllib.request.Request object at 0x808b92048>
```

Why problem exists only on production server?

Comment: The most likely cause (with the given information) is a firewall that blocks outgoing requests on your production server. To verify simply execute a `curl` or `wget` on the server and see if those work or not.

Comment: There are only two websites that deal with the problem. Another urls works fine...